# if var a = true then a == 1 is true but a == 2 is false. Why?

Tags: javascript

if `var a = true` then `a == 1` is `true` but `a == 2` is `false`. Why?    I understand that in javascript boolean expressions 0 casts to false and 1 casts to true. But what about the other integers. Why the above behavior?

Comment: All non-zero values are not false, but `true` can not be any non-zero value, it has to be one single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why? I understand that in javascript boolean expressions 0 casts to
>   false and 1 casts to true.

Because **`Number(true)` => `1`**

As per [spec of abstract equality expression evaluation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)

> 8. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.

Hence `a` is **first coerced into a Number** and then compared with 1.

Answer (score 2):

when you use == or != in js,the operands will be converted to the same type before making the comparison.when converting:

if there is a Boolean, true will be turned to 1 and false turned to 0;

```
    var a = true;
    a == 1;// a turned to 1 before compare,so true
    a == 2;// a turned to 1 before compare,so false
```

Comment: "*Forced restructuring*" - wat?

Comment: be forced to converted to the same type,i used google translation,,,have updated,not goog at english, so sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

This is to do with coercion. In the `a == 1` scenario, `a` is coerced into a an integer to compare again 1, `true` is coerced to `1`. In the second example, `a` is again coerced to `1`, so it doesn't equal `2`.

[Further reading on coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Answer (score 1):

That's probably inherited from binary world and it makes sense, because in binary 0 is false and 1 is true. Exactly, that is how type conversion been done for boolean types in javascript as well while comparing.

For boolean there are only 2 possibles, `true` or `false`. Hence in number/binary system 0 and 1 are apt to represent them.

Answer (score 1):

You may convert `1` to `True` and `True` to `1` but you can't convert other numerics to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Well because 0 = false and 1 = true. There are only two values for a boolean: true/false. So what should 2 be?

var has no type, it can be everything. Please consider also the == vs === operator.

```
var x = 1;
console.log(x === true);
console.log(x == true);
x = 2;
console.log(x === true);
console.log(x == true);
x = 0;
console.log(x === false);
console.log(x == false);
x = -1;
```

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/2aqGS/146/